# saving/loading array of objects using java serialization

Tags: java, serialization, file-io

I have the following class, which performs some calculations to fill its static arrays.

```
public class Amount implements Serializable{
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 8141477444408242243L;
      public static Amount values1[][] = new Amount[10][30];
      public static Amount values2[][] = new Amount[10][30];
      public static Amount values3[][] = new Amount[10][30];

      double highestValue;
      double highestAmount;
      double lowestAmount;
      double lowestValue;

      ...
}
```

As the calculations take 20 minutes or so, I am looking to store the arrays on file and load the values when the program starts. I am attempting to use the java serialization method and have the following functions

```
public static void loadFile(Amount[][] arr, String filename){
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        arr = (Amount[][])in.readObject();
        in.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
}

public static void saveFile(Amount[][] arr, String filename){
     try {
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
         out.writeObject(arr);
         out.flush();
         out.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e); 
      }
}
```

which I call like this `saveFile(values1, "valueOneSaveFile");` and `loadFile(values1, "valueOneSaveFile");`

I have run the program once, saving all the arrays to various files. The files have been created and look to be around the correct size. When I change my program to call the loadFile functions, the arrays do not appear to initialize correctly. I am getting null pointer exceptions when trying to read a value from the array (which appears to be empty after the load)

Comment: Have you considered using an embedded database instead of going out to file? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your LoadFile method.
Java passes parameters by value. In the case of objects a copy of the "pointer" is passed.
When you update the array:

```
arr = (Amount[][])in.readObject();
```

You are not updating Amount.values1 array, instead the local arr variable points to a new array.

You should change the method signature to:

```
public static Amount[][] loadFile(String filename)
```

And use it accordingly.

Comment: I am slightly confused though. So in the original code, the first argument of the `loadFile` function will be passed in as a pointer. The function then creates a copy of this pointer, and updates that copy to point to a different area of memory where the result of the file load (i.e. `in.readObject()`) is stored. The pointer sent to the function remains unchanged and still points to an empty array. Is this correct

Comment: There aren't really pointers in Java. I guess that it is more correct to say references. What you wrote above is correct. The original array variable is never initialized and thus you get a NullPointerException when you access it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the `readObject` and `writeObject` methods that you are implementing in your `Amount` class. A comprehensive example can be found [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45).

You might also consider using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to save/load your data. It is very easy to use, as shown [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).