# Groovy pickle alternative

Tags: file, serialization, groovy, set

I'm searching for something similar to Python's [pickle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickle_(Python)). I want to do like this example:

https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-session-after-login-with-Selenium-Python

**saving cookies**

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.quora.com')
# login code
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies() , open("QuoraCookies.pkl","wb"))
```

**loading cookies**

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.quora.com')
for cookie in pickle.load(open("QuoraCookies.pkl", "rb")):
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

I've tried many examples from the web without success. I saw the topics here as well.

In groovy case I'll :

```
Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
```

Variable allCookies should be serialized to file and deserialized later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java serialization is an option here. With credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860767/saving-loading-array-of-objects-using-java-serialization), here is an implementation:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie

def loadFile = { filename ->
    def result = null

    try {
        def fis = new FileInputStream(filename)
        def instream= new ObjectInputStream(fis)
        result = (Set<Cookie>) instream.readObject()
        instream.close()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e)
    }

    return result
}

def saveFile = { set, filename ->
    try {
        def fos = new FileOutputStream(filename)
        def out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)
        out.writeObject(set)
        out.flush()
        out.close()
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e) 
    }
}
```

and a sample driver program:

```
// ----------------------- main

if (args.size() >= 2) {
    def action = args[0]
    def file = args[1] 

    if (action == "write") {
        def cookies = new HashSet<Cookie>()
        cookies << new Cookie("Toronto", "Canada") 
        cookies << new Cookie("London", "UK") 
        cookies <<  new Cookie("Paris", "France") 

        saveFile(cookies, file)
    } else if (action == "read") {
        def cookies = loadFile(file)
        cookies.each { cookie ->
            println "${cookie.name} ${cookie.value}"
        }
    } else {
        println "Unknown action: " + action
    }
} else {
    println "Usage: groovy CookieManager.groovy [read|write] filename"
}
```

Example usage (a) with all above code in the same script and (b) assuming that `client-combined-3.0.0-beta2-nodeps.jar` [from here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) is on the classpath:

```
bash$ groovy CookieManager.groovy write set.dat
bash$ groovy CookieManager.groovy read set.dat
London UK
Toronto Canada
Paris France
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Cookie I'll try to find out why I think that this is the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273658/java-classnotfound-exception-when-working-with-objectinputstream-and-arraylist

Comment: I have updated the answer to mention that the Selenium jar (for Cookie) must be on the classpath. I thought this was obvious. Note that I have never used Selenium so I won't be able to explain much more than this.

Comment: 10x after last comment it was ok.